# how can I write a function for below task?

Tags: function

Write a function:

def solution(A)

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

Comment: Please show your attempt so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but a solution: loop thru 1 to N*max* (starting with `i` = 1) and check if the array includes `i`. When nothing was found, the result is 1.